# What are the differences between PWM signals and digital signals

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electronics

PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) is a way to handle analog devices and components with a digital output. What are the differences between those PWM and digital signals?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about physics.

Comment: Electrical engineering might be better?